# MediaElement is not playing video

Tags: video, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

Hi
I am trying to play a video (wmv) file using MediaElement. I have encoded the video in V8. I have set the properties of the file in Visual Studio as

Build Action: Resource
Copy to Destination Directory: Always Copy

Problem is that when I execute the code, the MediaElement play just 2 or 3 seconds of the file. No video is displayed. Just audio of 2 or 3 seconds is played but my file is a video file containing audio as well and its duration is 10seconds.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this issue?

Best Regards
Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you test your scenario in the emulator then (I found this in the suggested article):

NOTE: In windows phone 7 emulator the application can start the media player and the user can play music, but video is not rendered.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Now I understand. But... how will I play a video which is in my project folder? Its neither somewhere on the web nor on the user isolatedStorage. Its in my project folder. What path will i give to MediaPlayerLauncher.Media? Documentation says that it does not support relative URI.

Comment: I added this video to my project folder by right clicking the project name and then selecting Add -> Existing Item. I set Build Action: Resource. Now how to give its path to MediaPlayerLauncher.Media? If i write mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri("video.wmv", UriKind.Relative); , It throws InvalidOperationException. :-(

Comment: Thanks a lot kate. It worked. I changed the Build Action to Content and it worked. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Lets say that you have a sample file called "test.mp3" added in your project with build action Content in the Files folder. Then you can use something like:

mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri("Files/test.mp3", UriKind.Relative);

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the movie file is corrupt.

Have you checked the size is as it should be?
Have you tried other files?
Where are you playing from? IsoatedStorage or from within the XAP?

You can also try playing the file with the [MediaPlayerLauncher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to confirm that it is complete and not corrupt.
If it plays fine with the launcher please provide an exmaple of what you're actually trying to do in code.

Comment: I have tried playing it in windows media player 12 of windows 7 and its plays it without any problem.

Comment: Hi Matt Can you please send me a sample video file which can be played successfully using MediaElement? My email address is aqueelmirza@gmail.com

Comment: This is what i got from internet. I think video play support is not available in windows phone emulator. Am i right?    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: video play back is supported on the emulator but depending on your graphics card you may see some issues. If you click the emulator screen when it's playing this may force the display of the currently playing frame.

Comment: If you have a file which plays fine on the PC and meets the requirements in the msdn articl you linked then you shouldn't need another file.  Have you tried checking the file when on the phone/emulator? How are you getting it there from the PC? Have you tried playing it with the MediaPlayerLauncher?

Comment: I have tried playing it with MediaPlayerLauncher but nothing happens. It does not play the video. When i try to play it using MediaElement, only the first frame of video is displayed and also 2 or 3 seconds of audio is played then it stops. The video is played successfully when i play it with Windows Media Player 12 of Windows 7. I am using Windows Phone 7 to play the video because i dont have the device yet.